# Unable to figure out how to create and run my user-defined R function in Shiny with input text boxes

Tags: r, shiny

I've an R script for which I need to develop and intigrate a user-interface in `shiny` package in R.

My following is a part of R code that I'm trying to build the interface around:

```
# A random normal function to generate numbers with exact mean and SD
rnorm2 <- function(n,mean,sd) { mean+sd*scale(rnorm(n)) }
age <- rnorm2(n = 10000, mean = 55 , sd = 15)
cholestrol <- rnorm2(n = 10000, mean = 200 , sd = 30)
bp <- rnorm2(n = 10000, mean = 90 , sd = 25)
df <- cbind(age, cholestrol,bp)
Org_Data <- as.data.frame(df)
```

As there are 9 inputs (3 each for `age`, `cholestrol` and `bp`) I've created 9 input boxes in which user enters the input and then on a button click I want to run the `rnorm2` function that I created.

My shiny app code is as follows:

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("function1"),

    sidebarPanel( 
      #Age input
      textInput(inputId = "n1", 
                label = h4("Enter n for Age:"), 
                value = ""),

      textInput(inputId = "mean1", 
                label = h4("Enter mean for Age:"), 
                value = ""),

      textInput(inputId = "sd1", 
                label = h4("Enter sd for Age:"), 
                value = ""),

      #Cholestrol input
      textInput(inputId = "n1", 
                label = h4("Enter n for Cholestrol:"), 
                value = ""),

      textInput(inputId = "mean1", 
                label = h4("Enter mean for Cholestrol:"), 
                value = ""),

      textInput(inputId = "sd1", 
                label = h4("Enter sd for Cholestrol:"), 
                value = ""),


      #Blood Pressure input
      textInput(inputId = "n1", 
                label = h4("Enter n for Blood Pressure:"), 
                value = ""),

      textInput(inputId = "mean1", 
                label = h4("Enter mean for Blood Pressure:"), 
                value = ""),

      textInput(inputId = "sd1", 
                label = h4("Enter sd for Blood Pressure:"), 
                value = ""),


      actionButton(inputId = "input_action", label = "Show Inputs")),



    mainPanel( 
      h2("Input Elements"), # title with HTML helper
      textOutput("td"))


  ))
```

But I'm completely helpless at figuring out how to put the R code I mentioned at the beginning into the `server.R` file. Can I start with simply defining the function?? And then how to run that function on those inputs taken from the user and then save the output into each of theose variables: `age`, `cholestrol` and `bp`???

server.R:

```
library(shiny)

#defining a function
rnorm2 <- function(n,mean,sd) { mean+sd*scale(rnorm(n)) }

shinyServer(function(input, output){

  #Don't know how run the function and save the output into the variables 
  age <- 
  cholestrol <- 
  bp <-  


  })

})
```

This is my first day with shiny and all the server.R code samples on the internet are kinda going over my head. But I really need to turn this around today. Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only dependency I added was `library(DT)` which is an exceptionally useful package.

You'll notice that you needed to make your input ids unique in the `ui.R` and use an `eventReactive` to instruct shiny to wait for the input button.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("function1"),

  sidebarPanel( 
    #Age input
    numericInput(inputId = "n", 
                 label = h4("Enter n:"), 
                 value = ""),

    numericInput(inputId = "mean1", 
                 label = h4("Enter mean for Age:"), 
                 value = ""),

    numericInput(inputId = "sd1", 
                 label = h4("Enter sd for Age:"), 
                 value = ""),

    #Cholestrol input        
    numericInput(inputId = "mean2", 
                 label = h4("Enter mean for Cholestrol:"), 
                 value = ""),

    numericInput(inputId = "sd2", 
                 label = h4("Enter sd for Cholestrol:"), 
                 value = ""),


    #Blood Pressure input
    numericInput(inputId = "mean3", 
                 label = h4("Enter mean for Blood Pressure:"), 
                 value = ""),

    numericInput(inputId = "sd3", 
                 label = h4("Enter sd for Blood Pressure:"), 
                 value = ""),


    actionButton(inputId = "input_action", label = "Show Inputs")),



  mainPanel( 
    h2("Input Elements"), # title with HTML helper
    dataTableOutput("inputs"),
    h2("Results"),
    dataTableOutput("results")
  )))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

rnorm2 <- function(n,mean,sd) { mean+sd*scale(rnorm(n)) }

shinyServer(function(input, output){

  data <- eventReactive(input$input_action, {
    matrix(
      c(rnorm2(input$n, input$mean1, input$sd1),
        rnorm2(input$n, input$mean2, input$sd2),
        rnorm2(input$n, input$mean3, input$sd3)), byrow = FALSE,
      ncol = 3)
  })

  inpts <- eventReactive(input$input_action, {
    data.frame(Type = c("Age", "Cholestorol", "BP"), 
               N = c(input$n, input$n, input$n),
               Mean = c(input$mean1, input$mean2, input$mean3),
               SD = c(input$sd1, input$sd2, input$sd3))
  }) 

  output$inputs <- renderDataTable({
    inpts()
  })
  output$results <- renderDataTable({
    set <- as.data.frame(data())
    colnames(set) <- c("Age", "BP", "Cholestorol")
    set
  })

})
```

Comment: Wow.. that was beautiful.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, I tried to bring all the three variables under one dataframe: full_df <- eventReactive(input$input_action, {
    data.frame(age_r, chol_r, bp_r)
    })
  
  output$full_df_r <- renderDataTable({
    full_df()
  }) But it was not recognizing `age_r` can't I use that age_r from `output$age_r` as a vector `age_r`??

Comment: Is there a way to combine all those 3 variables `age`, `cholestrol` and `bp` into one dataframe in server.R?? How to achieve that?

Comment: only if `input$n1`, `input$n2` and `input$n3` are all the same number

Comment: Yes they are all the same number.. infact in my updated code I removed `n2` and `n3` and used `n1` itself at all three places. So, how do I combine `age`, `cholestrol` and `bp` into one variable and store it as a matrix?

Comment: I want to store them under one matrix variable because, in my further steps in code I to multiply that matrix with three columns (age, cholestrol, bp) with a correlation matrix. That's where I'm stuck, so I need to figure out how to combine those three variables into a single matrix... Please help!

Comment: @LearneR  Please see my edits, you can now call `data()` from other `reactive` expressions (they need not be `eventReactive` since the Shiny understands the dependency). I just changed it to a `matrix` object

Comment: @LearneR whoops, had a bug in there -- the updated solution should be what you desire

Comment: yes I too was just rectifying them in my code as well... Thank you so much.. Honestly! And one small clarification: the `data` variable is a matrix and now I can go ahead and use it for my matrix multiplication, right??

Comment: You can call the matrix with `data()`, e.g. `reactive({ m <- data(); m %*% t(m) })`

Comment: Thank you so very much, mkemp6 :-)

Comment: hey can you please help me out with this question???: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884519/unable-to-deduce-how-to-connect-ui-r-and-server-r-with-an-r-script-to-run-in-the