# How to pass values from input boxes of shiny UI back into the variables in an R script and run it?

Tags: r, shiny

I've the following code in `source.R` which I'm planning to run from shiny. Currently there are hardcoded values in the script (such as 10000, 55, 15, 200 and etc and also some matrix correlation elements below those values):

```
rnorm2 <- function(n,mean,sd) { mean+sd*scale(rnorm(n)) }
var1 <- rnorm2(n = 10000, mean = 55 , sd = 15)
var2 <- rnorm2(n = 10000, mean = 200 , sd = 30)
var3 <- rnorm2(n = 10000, mean = 90 , sd = 25)
var4 <- rnorm2(n = 10000, mean = 8 , sd = 3)

R = matrix(cbind(1,.80,.2, .4,  .80,1,.7, .6,  .2,.7,1,.65, .4, .6, .65, 1),nrow=4)
```

I've developed a shiny interface that takes input from the user from the numeric input boxes shown in the screenshot of the UI:

[image]

Now, I want to connect the input entered from those numeric boxes to the variables in the `source.R` script that I have, in the place of those hardcoded values (such as 10000, 55, 15, 200 and etc and also the matrix correlation elements below those values).

Actually this is a new approach that I've decided to follow now. Previously I was following a different approach from the answers posted to my question: [Unable to figure out how to create and run my user-defined R function in Shiny with input text boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725156/unable-to-figure-out-how-to-create-and-run-my-user-defined-r-function-in-shiny-w) 
I had to choose this new approach because in the previous approach I'm haivng to re-create the entire R code written in the `source.R` again in the server.R file (you can see the file from the linked question's URL). And also the lines of code are increasing with increasing complexity of the requirement.

So, I thought it best to connect the interface with the already existing R script and run the code and display the output directly in shiny. It sounded smart that way instead of rewriting entire code in server.R file. Also, in the previous approach I've observed the app running very slow down the line when I was implementing various other things.

Please help me with this technique. I'm very new to shiny. I've been working with shiny only for a week now. But I'm really in great need of implementing this new appraoch. It makes things a lot easier and efficient.

Comment: If you can reorganize your `source.R` file and create a function that takes input and returns what you want, then you can simple `source(source.R)` in `server.R` and then run the function.

Comment: Ok.. So I guess I need to write a function that takes inputs for each of my numeric input boxes into my source.R file. I just found this: `readinteger <- function()
{ 
  n <- readline(prompt="Enter an integer: ")
  return(as.integer(n))
}` but can you please suggest me on how do I make `readline()` take input from shiny instead of R command line ??

Comment: The input from Shiny are saved in these variables (as shown in the answer of your other question): `input$n, input$mean1, input$sd1, input$n, input$mean2, input$sd2, input$n, input$mean3, input$sd3`. What you need is a function that takes these value and create your result. Then in the `server.R` file, `source(source.R)`, and then `your_function(input$n, input$mean1, ......)`

Comment: ok.. will try out your suggestions.. Thank you :)

Comment: @warmoverflow hey, I tried implementing your suggested appraoch on a short example.. But kinda stuck mid-way. Can you plz help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884519/unable-to-deduce-how-to-connect-ui-r-and-server-r-with-an-r-script-to-run-in-the Thanks a lot!