# Unable to deduce how to connect ui.R and server.R with an R script to run in the background

Tags: r, shiny

I was trying to follow suggestions given by a commenter (named: warmoverflow) in a question I posted yesterday: [How to pass values from input boxes of shiny UI back into the variables in an R script and run it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35859083/how-to-pass-values-from-input-boxes-of-shiny-ui-back-into-the-variables-in-an-r)

I decided to try the approach he proposed firstly in a short example. So, I created an R script `mathops.R` containing a function with minor math operations. It is as follows:

mathops.R:

```
mathops <- function(a,b) {
  print(paste0("Addition of two number is: ", a+b))
  print(paste0("Multiplication of two number is: ", a*b))
}
```

I developed a UI with two text boxes from which input will taken for the above mentioned varaibles `a` and `b` and also an action button to display the output. It is as follows:

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Inputting from Interface to Script"),

  sidebarPanel( 
    #'a' input
    textInput(inputId = "a", 
              label = h4("Enter a:"), 
              value = ""),

    textInput(inputId = "b", 
              label = h4("Enter b:"), 
              value = ""),

    actionButton(inputId = "input_action", label = "Show Inputs")),



  mainPanel( 
    h2("Input Elements"))
    textOutput("td"))


))
```

and now as he suggested, I was trying to develop the code for `server.R` file:

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
source(mathops.R)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  a <- eventReactive( input$input_action, {
    input$a 
  })

  b <- eventReactive( input$input_action, {
    input$b
  })

  output$td <- renderDataTable({
    mathops()
  })

}
```

But here is where I'm facing an impasse. I just couldn't think of how to connect that `mathops.R` script into `server.R` file so that it will take the input coming from the input boxes on the UI and pass those values into the variables `a` and `b` of the `mathops()` function in the R script shown above.

I'm new to shiny. What am I missing or misunderstanding here? How to solve this situation?

Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working version with some changes from your original code. As pointed out in the other answer, there are a few errors in your code. In addition, I changed textOutput to htmlOutput. In server.R, I put all code inside the `observeEvent` environment.

In general, your method in your R script needs to **return** something suitable for process in `server.R`. For example, in this case, it returns a string, which `server.R` renders as text, and `ui.R` in turn renders as HTML.

Any variable/data that is accessible in `server.R` (including any files that it `source`) can be displayed in the ui. What you need is (1) a suitable render method to render this data in `server.R` (2) a suitable output container to hold the output display in `ui.R`

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    headerPanel("Inputting from Interface to Script"),

    sidebarPanel( 
        #'a' input
        numericInput(inputId = "a", 
                  label = h4("Enter a:"), 
                  value = 3),

        numericInput(inputId = "b", 
                  label = h4("Enter b:"), 
                  value = 4),

        actionButton(inputId = "input_action", label = "Show Inputs")),

    mainPanel( 
        h2("Input Elements"),
        htmlOutput("td")),
        # use dataTableOuput to display the result of renderDataTable. Just like the render methods, there are many output methods available for different kind of outputs. See Shiny documentation.
        dataTableOutput("table")


))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
source("mathops.R")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {        

    observeEvent(input$input_action, {
        a = input$a
        b = input$b
        output$td <- renderText({
            mathops(a,b)
        })
    })
    # Use renderDataTable to convert mat2 to a displayable object. There are many other render methods for different kind of data and output, you can find them in Shiny documentation
    output$table <- renderDataTable(data.frame(mat2))

})
```

mathops.R

```
mathops <- function(a,b) {
    return(paste0("Addition of two number is: ", a+b, br(), "Multiplication of two number is: ", a*b))
}

mat1 <- matrix(sample(1:16), ncol=4)
mat2 <- matrix(sample(1:25), ncol=5)
```

Comment: just to clarify.. In the actual task that I'm trying to achieve, inside of my `source.R` script, in addition to the function, I have lots of other commands, such as `for` loops, `dataframe` manupulations, applying linear regression models and generating plots on the model's results and writing those resultant dataframes to csv using `write.csv()` and various other such commands.. So when I'm linking my `source.R` in the `server.R` file, the entire script with of all those commands will be executed right??

Comment: If you implement all of them as functions, then only the functions will be imported, but they will not be executed until you call these functions, like in the example above where you call `mathops(a,b)`

Comment: Ok. Let's say, I just created two matrices under the `mathops()` function in the `mathops.R` script. `mat1 <- matrix(sample(1:16), ncol=4)` and  `mat2 <- matrix(sample(1:25), ncol=5)` and executed the app again. When I went back to Rstudio, I could now see `mat1` and `mat2` in the environment, which means they were created. Now, my doubt was is it possible to output them in shiny?? If yes, how can I achieve that?? (sorry if I'm asking too many questions. I'm just trying to keep my understanding clear as I'm only beginning out on actually working with shiny) Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Any variable/data that is accessible in `server.R` can be displayed in the ui. What you need is (1) a suitable render method to render this data in `server.R` (2) a suitable output container to hold the output display in the frontend. I've updated my answer to include the matrices.

Answer (score 1):

You had to do a couple things:

1. Switch from using `textInput` to `numericInput` in your `ui.R`
2. Your `mainPanel` arguments were not being parsed correctly
3. You needed to use `renderPrint` instead of `renderDataTable` if you are going to be using printed text
4. You can call `a` and `b` as reactive objects, but `mathops` is just a regular function:

*Note: I moved the `mathops` function definition into the `server.R` for simplicity*

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Inputting from Interface to Script"),

  sidebarPanel(

    numericInput(inputId = "a",
              label = h4("Enter a:"),
              value = ""),

    numericInput(inputId = "b",
              label = h4("Enter b:"),
              value = ""),

    actionButton(inputId = "input_action", label = "Show Inputs")),

  mainPanel(
    h2("Input Elements"),
    textOutput("td")
    )
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

mathops <- function(a, b) {
  print(paste0("Addition of two number is: ", a + b))
  print(paste0("Multiplication of two number is: ", a * b))
}

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  a <- eventReactive( input$input_action, {
    input$a
  })

  b <- eventReactive( input$input_action, {
    input$b
  })

  output$td <- renderPrint({
    mathops(a(), b())
  })

})
```

Comment: thank you so much for detailing out where I went wrong. Made me realize that I completely missed on the nuances of parsing. I will mind them from now on.. and also thanks for showing how to define and use a function in the `server.R` itself.