# How to run a function that gets data from inside eventReactive and plot in table?

Tags: r, function, shiny, reactive-programming

I'm very new to shiny and am having some trouble and have been searching all day, so hopefully someone can help me.  Once an action button (actionButton, on UI) is selected by a user, I would like the server script to call a function (evenReactive in server) I wrote (myfunction, see below) that uses the input items from the UI and gets the right parameters I need to run myfunction and produce a n X2 data matrix that will be plotted as a table (renderTable in server, below). The data is a n X 2 matrix.

I have some sample code below. It's not the entre code, so you will not see the UI with the inputs I am putting in my function, or the server parts associated. But, it is the part I am trying to fix. I hope that's ok. I don't need the renderText, but when I take it out I get an error.  Sorry for the formatting. Copy and pasting changed it a bit.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage
     (column(4,actionButton("gobutton", "Run"),verbatimTextOutput("ntext1")), 
      column(4, DT::dataTableOutput("table",width = "75%"))))

library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) 


  ntext1 <- eventReactive(input$gobutton, {
            if (input$gobutton==1){ 
              data=myfunction(input$checkbox,input$dateRange)}
   })


  output$ntext1 <- renderText({ntext1()})

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    data
  })
))

myfunction <-function(All,date1,date2,source_cd,tran_cd,airline_list,mag_level) {
 print(All); print(date1); print(date2); print(source_cd);print(tran_cd);print(airline_list);print(mag_level)

    setwd("C:/Users/TRomano/Documents/Projects/TrendAnalysis/Data")
    data = read.csv("Airlines.csv",header = TRUE)
    return(data)
  }
```

Comment: By indenting your code you can get it formatted properly. Don't apologize, you are supposed to condense the problem! However you could articulate the actual question a little better.

Comment: One someone clicks the action button, I would like it to go the the eventReactive (server) and run myfunction. I don't know if it should be outputted by text. But, from what I saw online actionbuttons go with verbatimTextOutput.  When I run it, runs the first couple of lines of the script (I just have some print remarks to see if it is working), but once it gets to the part of loading the data it freezes. This is the function. It's short and not complicated, just to get it going.

Comment: It helps if you put everything in your original question, and also properly format your code. You can do it in RStudio (Code > Reformat Code), and then copy things over, and select everything, and click the {} button).

Comment: I think it has to do with copy  and pasting to this comment section. I reformat it in R and then paste it and it looks like a disaster. Sorry about that.@warmoverflow

Comment: What you should do is to edit your original question

Comment: reformatted. hope it helps.

Comment: I answered a question yesterday that was similar in nature to yours, so it might help. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884519/unable-to-deduce-how-to-connect-ui-r-and-server-r-with-an-r-script-to-run-in-the/35901074

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this type of problem I like to make use of `reactiveValues()`that are designed to store data in a reactive way.

Here is a simple app (single app, not split into server & ui) that demonstrates what I think you are trying to do

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
        column(width = 4,
                     actionButton("gobutton", "Run")
        column(width = 4, 
                     DT::dataTableOutput("table",
                                         width = "75%"))))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){ 

    rv <- reactiveValues()
    rv$data <- NULL

    observe({    ## will 'observe' the button press

        if(input$gobutton){ 
            print("here")  ## for debugging
            rv$data <- myfunction()   ## store the data in the reactive value
            rv$data
            }
        })

    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        ## The data has been stored in our rv, so can just return it here
        rv$data
    })
})

myfunction <- function(){
    data <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                       val = letters[1:3])
    return(data)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi @Symbolix,  Thank you so much for the help I think I'm getting close. When I run the script above, I get an error and I'm not sure what it means.                                                                                                    Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7446
Warning: Error in force: object 'ui' not found
Stack trace (innermost first):
    40: force
    39: uiHttpHandler
    38: shinyApp
     1: shiny::runApp
Error in force(ui) : object 'ui' not found

Comment: How are you running the script? This one will work by just copy & pasting direct into the R console

Comment: Some useful references are [single-file shiny apps](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/single-file.html) and [app formats and launching apps](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/app-formats.html)

Comment: @tracy you're welcome. On Stackoverflow.com the best way to show appreciation is to up-vote, or accept an answer that helps you (by pressing the arrows and/or tick at the top left of this answer)

Comment: This deserves to be checked as the right answer. I couldn't make your example work by copying it either, but the idea is there. Amazing, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

library(shiny)

library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(

dashboardHeader(title = "Company Name"),

dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(

menuItem("Results Table", tabName = "ResultsTable", icon = icon

("ResultsTable")),

dashboardBody(

```
tabItems(

  tabItem(tabName tabItem(tabName = "ResultsTable",
          fluidPage(  
            headerPanel(
            fluidRow(
              column(4,
                     selectInput("sour",
                                 "Source Type:",
                                 c("All",
                                   unique(as.character(data_source_cd)))), offset=2
              ),
              column(4,
                     selectInput("tran",
                                 "Transaction Type:",
                                 c("All",
                                   unique(as.character(tran_cd)))))),
            # Create a new row for the table.
            fluidRow(column(8, DT::dataTableOutput("table",width = "75%"),offset = 2))))))
```

library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
       ntext1 <- eventReactive(input$gobutton, {

```
if (input$dateRange[2]<input$dateRange[1]){print("You selected the date range option;however, the end date entered occurs before the starting date")}else{
  output$ntext1 <- renderText({print("Analysis complete...")});
  observe({   
    if(input$gobutton){ 
      rv$data <- myfunction()          }
  })
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    data <- rv$data
    if (input$sour != "All") {
      data <- data[data[,5] == input$sour,]
    }else{data}
    if (input$tran != "All") {
      data <-data[data[,6] == input$tran,]
    }else{data} 
  }))
}})
```

Once an action button is selected on the main page of my dashboard(not shown), myfunction runs analysis with the inputs from the main dashboard page. On another tab, a table will show once the analysis is complete. There are drop down menus (input$tran, input$sour) that will reduce what is in the table depending on what the user selects. If there are any errors in the input, a warning of text comes up on the main dashboard page and the tab with the table will not be created until the correct inputs are selected.

The observe function allowed me to run my function and the output data of the function set to a variable I could later use to create the table (shown).

THis is my first time posting. Any questions feel free to ask.